# keep one column's data in pandas and show all NANs from other columns only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Goal: Id like to still show who the person is so that I can display the NANs associated with them so that I can quickly find who is missing info.

Consider this dataset:

```
df:
Name            Phone            Address
John Doe        NAN               123 lane
Jenny Gump      222-222-2222      NAN
Larry Bean      NAN               561 road
Harry Smidlap   111-111-1111       555 highway
```

I'd like to clean the data up and show something like this (similar to an excel view when filtering for blanks):
Then maybe populate the empty data with something that says "Data exists" or just leave it blank. Im open to suggestions. And also drop the rows that have all data populated.

```
df:
Name        Phone            Address
John Doe     NAN               
Jenny Gump                     NAN
Larry Bean    NAN
```

I've tried:

```
df[df.isnull().any(axis=1)]
```

That works great but I have a big data source and I see a lot of unnecessary info that already has data. I only care about seeing the person's name and what their missing.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you require the `Name` column to be intact, you can just select other columns except `Name` and mask them, then create another data frame `df2` which removes all the `NaN` values. After that you can just drop the indexes in `df2` from `df` which you give you rows with only the `NaN` values as follows.

```py
df.mask((df.columns != 'Name') & (df.notnull()), "", inplace=True)
df2 = df.dropna()
df.drop(df2.index, inplace=True)
```

This should give you the following output.

```py
Name        Phone            Address
John Doe     NAN               
Jenny Gump                     NAN
Larry Bean    NAN
```

Comment: ugh so simple! thanks that worked. Im able to see all of the name's and then I can see which columns have NaNs. Id like to be able to not show the names that have no NaNs. I updated my example at the top, otherwise I have a ton of blank space in the data frame.

Comment: @aero8991 I have updated the answer, please accept it if solves your issue.

Comment: thanks for updating That worked!  my data has 60 rows and 24 columns, which was down from 286 rows! So I can see all the NAN's in pandas but when I print to a csv/xlsx file they disappear ? Is it because they were dropped in df2?

Comment: @aero8991 Yeah, its because they were dropped

Answer (score 1):

[Mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) (replacing values where the condition is true) any place where it is not null with an empty string.

```
df.mask(df.notnull(), '')
```

This operates over multiple dimensions, passing a 2D set of true/false answers to the question "Replace or not?". And where it is true, it send the contents to `/dev/null`, while where it is not, it allows them to remain precariously.

Comment: This is awesome! The thing about this solution is that it erases ALL the columns, is there anyway to keep the 'Name' column populated?